# MySQL Trigger IF Statement OR not workign when two conditions match

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I'm fairly new to MySQL Trigger sintax and I'm having a problem that I could not find a clear answer anywhere.

i have a quite simple IF statment, it enters on the IF, if one OR the other condition is met, but never if both are.

i want to have some action going if one field or other field of the updated table changes, but if i update both fields it does not work.

Keep in mind that this trigger happens AFTER UPDATE of the table here's my SAMPLE code for easier visualization:

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.field1 <=> OLD.field1 OR NEW.field2 <=> OLD.field2 THEN
        #action happens here
    END IF;
END
```

The ACTUAL code:

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.margem_consig <=> OLD.margem_consig OR NEW.margem_cartao <=> OLD.margem_cartao THEN
        INSERT INTO historico_margem (idmatricula, margem, margem_cartao, margem_confiavel, margem_anterior_con, margem_anterior_car)
        VALUES (NEW.idmatricula, NEW.margem_consig, NEW.margem_cartao, NEW.margem_confiavel, OLD.margem_consig, OLD.margem_cartao);
    END IF;
END
```

So, if on update BOTH fields 1 and 2 changes, the condition is never met, can anybody shed me some light?

Also, sorry for any misspelling

Comment: Post your complete trigger code not just a part off it..

Comment: @RaymondNijland but everything else works accordingly. Also, I just changed the name of the fields for better visualisation, the action was a simple test INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the <=> operator, replaced it with != and it worked as expected.

thanks for everyone's time!

CORRECTED SAMPLE CODE:

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.field1 != OLD.field1 OR NEW.field2 != OLD.field2 THEN
        #action happens here
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

To test difference please use the <> operator.

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.field1 <> OLD.field1 OR NEW.field2 <> OLD.field2 THEN
        #action happens here
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: Could you please try to debug you program by putting SELECT New.field1; and other values to see what we have (before the if statement).

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug a MySQL Trigger... but all the values are correct, as I said, if the condition 1 or condition 2 are met everything goes accordainly, but never when both conditions are met.

so i imagine the values themselves are correct

Comment: Add the select like i said and run an UPDATE manually in mysql (via command line in your terminal). What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure where to put the SELECT statement, it gives me the error 'SQL (1415): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger'. 

Also, I'm using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Another way to debug a trigger is to create a temporary log table. In you trigger simply insert the values you want to check (New.field1...)

Comment: the action that happens is exactly that, saving those new and old values in a history table, and it saves correctly when one of the conditions are met (both fields), I'll edit with the actual code

Comment: Yes insert in the history table before the if statement to see why it does not go through the if statement

Comment: I did that, both INSERTS (before and inside IF) does the same thing, everything seems ok. Also, thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: As an alternative, if you are really blocked you could use http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88fcf to help us to debug your code.

Comment: all the values are correct, I think the problem is at the sintax of the IF statement. that OR is a exclusive OR, I need an inclusive type of "OR"

Comment: In the end was the '<=>' i replaced it with '!=' and it worked properly...